Is ValidationError cached in python unit tests?
I want to test the reaction to a failure in a rather complex pydantic validation. For that I wrote a unit test like that:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from unittest.mock import patch
from pydantic import ValidationError
from pydantic_core import InitErrorDetails

from my_module import my_validation_function

class TestPydanticModel(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("my_module.MyPydanticModel.model_validate")
    def test_failure(self, mock_validate: MagicMock) -> None:
        mock_validate.side_effect = ValidationError.from_exception_data(
            "some_error",
            [ InitErrorDetails( 
                msg="Test Message",
                type="value_error",
                ctx={"message": "test message", "error": {}},
                input=""
            ) ]
        test_data={"data": "with errors"}
        response=my_validation_function(test_data)
        <assertions to test reaction to failure>
            

The actual validations are of no concern here.
The strange thing is: If I run this test on it's own it succeeds completely fine. But if I run it in context with the whole file, the ValidationError that gets thrown is not the one I defined here. It is one from an completely unrelated test.
I can already see this if I put a breakpoint right after the definition of the side_effect that it is the wrong error here.
Any idea how that can happen and what I can do about it?
I am using Python 3.10.12 with pydantic 2.8.2, pydantic_core 2.20.1

Found the error. A completely different test monkey patched
ValidationError.errors.
Reversing that patch solved the issue.
